# How to change Tox command with command-line parameters

Tags: python, django, django-unittest, tox

How do you append options to the command [Tox](https://testrun.org/tox/latest/config.html) runs by appending that option to Tox? Specifically, how do you run a specific Django unittest with Tox?

I'm trying to wrap Tox around some Django unittests, and I can run all unittests with `tox`, which runs `django-admin.py test --settings=myapp.tests.settings myapp.tests.Tests`.

However, I'd like to run a specific test at `myapp.tests.Tests.test_somespecificthing`, which would mean telling Tox to append ".test_somespecificthing" to the end of the command it runs, but I can't figure out how to do this.

The docs say to use "-- " to pass in additional arguments to the underlying command, but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 18):

Try adding `{posargs}` in the commands section of your tox.ini, like this:

```
commands =
    python manage.py test {posargs}
```

Then at the command line, something like:

```
tox -- --pattern='some_specific_test.py'
```

Everything after the `--` will be substituted in as `{posargs}`.

Read the official documentation [here](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/general.html#interactively-passing-positional-arguments).

Comment: I've been looking for this answer 45 minutes :) Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's the latest doc for tox positional arguments: [Substitions for positional arguments in commands](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html#substitutions-for-positional-arguments-in-commands)